# storing private and public keys in database

Tags: java, jsp

how to store and retrive private and public keys in database using  jdbc.
I found the following error when i'm tried

```
      X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(resultSet.getBytes("secretkey"));
        if(name.startsWith("AGENT"))
          {
          key = (PrivateKey) rsaKeyFac.generatePrivate(keySpec);//this line error
           System.out.println(key);
            session.setAttribute("key", key);
        response.sendRedirect("agentPage.jsp");
```

Comment: great what type of error, and how is this error related to JSP or Database?

Comment: What is the error? Surely you can be more descriptive than "this line error" ...?

Comment: Your title and problem seems to be mismatched. You might consider adding "error while generating private key" or something like that..

Answer (score -1):

Although you have not exactly stated what is the error thrown but the usual way to store keys is to get the bytes and convert it into Hex or Base64 String and store in a varchar field in database. While retrieving you can decode it and get byte array back.